# How to Lock a form for editing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Im using visual basic 2010. Preparing a program. In my program when user presses the button on main form, form2 will be shown. While form2 is on i dont want user to make any change on main form. But he must see the main form in the background. There is an example on visual basic program. In visual Basic 2010 when i press tools>options "options window" is shown and when i try to press visual basic main window, a sound comes and options window blinks. So it prevent me to reach main window. How can i do this in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make Form2 modal.  That will ensure the other forms remain visible, but inactive.  I'm not a VB person but from what I read Form.ShowDialog should do what you want.
Check out [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets13p4.html), it explains the whole procedure.